# The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.7.2

I'm trying to create a generic include, but I get this error. What is wrong? Thank you.

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties.

```
_repository.FindWithIncludes(..., new List<...>
    {
        x => x.Property1,
        x => x.Property2,
    });   

 public ICollection<TEntity> FindWithIncludes(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> currentExpression, List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> propertiesToInclude)
    {
        using (var customContext = new TContext())
        {
            return customContext.Set<TEntity>().Include(x => propertiesToInclude.Select(currentProperty => currentProperty)).Where(currentExpression).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Include` cannot be used this way:

```
.Include(x => propertiesToInclude.Select(currentProperty => currentProperty)
```

What you need is the equivalent of calling `Include` for each expression of the list:

```
.Include(x => x.Property1)
.Include(x => x.Property2)
...
.Include(x => x.PropertyN)
```

which can be achieved with code like this:

```
var query = customContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
foreach (var property in propertiesToInclude)
    query = query.Include(property); 
return query.Where(currentExpression).ToList();
```

or the same with using `Aggregate` method:

```
return propertiesToInclude
    .Aggregate(customContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable(), (q, p) => q.Include(p))
    .Where(currentExpression).ToList();
```